# Problema con un upload file y Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estimada comunidad, les comento que hice un sript para subir archivos en al servidor. Use html5, jquery/ajax y php. 
Hasta ahi todo bien, el tema es que ahora quiero hacer que me salga un alert de tipo confirm en el caso de que el nombre del archivo ya exista en el servidor. 
El problema lo tengo con la implementación de Ajax.

Acá paso a dejar mi codigo, creo que tengo un error de logica, ya que soy un lammer jaja.
A continuacion dejo el script ajax:

```
$(function(){
    $("#formuploadajax").on("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var f = $(this);
        var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("formuploadajax"));
        formData.append("dato", "valor");
       $('#target').hide();
        $('#mensaje').html('<center><strong>¡Atención!</strong> El archivo se está subiendo. Esto puede demorar unos segundos...</center>');
        //aca verifico si existe (en teoria :-p)
        $.ajax({
            url: "php/verificarArchivo.php",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "html", 
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false

            success:function(r){
  if(r==1){

    //si existe pregunta si desea reemplazar
alertify.confirm('El archivo existe, ¿Desea reemplazar?', 
      function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "php/uploadimage.php", //php para subir archivo
            type: "post",
            dataType: "html", 
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
                          success:function(r){
if(r==1){

    alertify.success("Actualizado con exito :)");
  }else{
    alertify.error("Fallo el servidor :(");
  }
   }


});

      }, function(){ alertify.error('Se cancelo')};


        //si no existe lo subo con uploadimage.php
          } else {
             $.ajax({
            url: "php/uploadimage.php",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "html", 
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
            success:function(r){
                if(r==1){

               alertify.success("Actualizado con exito :)");
                  }else{
               alertify.error("Fallo el servidor :(");
             }
              }
              });

            }

                });

            });
           });
```

Disculpas si le duelen los ojos. La consola no me tira ningún error pero no hace ninguna de las funciones.

Tambien dejo el script que si me funciona, pero este nada mas sube el archivo:

```
    $(function(){
    $("#formuploadajax").on("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var f = $(this);
        var formData = new 
       FormData(document.getElementById("formuploadajax"));
        formData.append("dato", "valor");
       $('#target').hide();
        $('#mensaje').html('<center><strong>¡Atención!</strong> El archivo 
         se está subiendo. Esto puede demorar unos segundos...</center>');
        //formData.append(f.attr("name"), $(this)[0].files[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: "php/uploadimage.php",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "html", 
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
   processData: false
        })
            .done(function(res){
                $("#mensaje").html("Listo!"); 
                window.location.reload();

            });
    });
});
```

La idea sería que en base a este código ampliar para que coteje si existe con anterioridad el nombre en la bd. De ser asi que pregunte si desea reemplazar. Y en el caso de que no exista, que lo suba sin consultar.

Comment: Lo ideal es que este guardando el nombre del archivo en una DB  para luego llamarlo. Lo que debes de hacer primero no es cargar el archivo, si no obtener el nombre únicamente para hacer la consulta de si existe o no, y ahí si mira si reemplaza o no

Comment: si, eso es lo que intento hacer. con la llamada verificarArchivo.php ahi compruebo si existe, si existe pregunta si desea reemplazar, y ejecuta uploadimage.php.

Comment: En teoría parece que la lógica esta bien, tal vez sea que el js no esta esperando las respuestas del servidor, intente con poner 'async:false' en la petición AJAX, para que sea asyncronica y espere la respuesta antes de continuar.

Comment: si, pero estoy construyendo mal el código, la sintaxis no se si es la correcta. Ahi deje mi codigo como lo tenia funcional antes de hacer la verificacion de si existe o no el archivo. Este si me funciona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pruebe así, separando las peticiones en funciones:

1. obtenga solo el nombre del archivo, y haga la petición para consultar si existe o no:

```js
function uploadFileControler() {
  // OBTIENE EL ARCHIVO
  var file = document.getElementById("formuploadajax");
  // OBTIENE SOLO EL NOMBRE DEL ARCHIVO
  var fileName = file.files[0].name;

  $('#target').hide();
  $('#mensaje').html(
    '<center><strong>¡Atención!</strong>' +
    'El archivo se está subiendo. ' +
    'Esto puede demorar unos segundos...</center>'
  );

  //guarda la respuesta de si existe o no el archivo
  var existFile = checkFile(fileName);
};

//hace una petición al servidor para verificar 
//si existe o no ya el archivo
function checkFile(name) {
  var exist = false; //guarda un booleano si existe o no

  //petición para verificar existencia
  $.ajax({
    url: "php/verificarArchivo.php",
    type: "post",
    async: false, //esto hace que el script espere la respuesta del servidor antes de continuar
    data: fileName, //envia unicamente el nombre, lo verifica en php y retorna la respuesta
    success: function(response) {
      //si existe
      if (response === 1) {
        exist = true;
      }
    }
  });

  return exist;
};
```

2. Defina una función para que no repita la petición para cargar el archivo y la llame cuando lo quiera:

```js
//petición para cargar el archivo
function uploadFile(file){
  //formatData para el archivo antes de enviarlo
  var data = new FormData(file);

  //petición
  $.ajax({
    url: "php/uploadimage.php", //php para subir archivo
    type: "post",
    async: false,
    dataType: "html",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
    success: function(r) {
      if (r == 1) {
        alertify.success("Actualizado con exito :)");
      } else {
        alertify.error("Fallo el servidor :(");
      }
    }
  });
};
```

3. Ahora una función que con la respuesta de si existe o no, defina como cargar el archivo, si con verificación o lo suba de una vez

```js
//decide si pedir verificación para reemplazar archivo o subirlo de una vez
function responseFile(exist){
  //define que hacer si existe o no existe
  //si existe el archivo
  if (exist) {
    alertify.confirm(
      'El archivo existe, ¿Desea reemplazar?',
      uploadFile(file),
      alertify.error('Se cancelo')
    );
  }else{
    uploadFile(file);
  }
}
```

4. por ultimo queda llamar la función anterior pasando como parámetro la respuesta del servidor de si existe o no el archivo:

```js
  //guarda la respuesta de si existe o no el archivo
  /*var existFile = checkFile(fileName);*/
  responseFile(existFile);
```

completo seria así:

```js
//llama a esta funcion con un onclick en el boton de subir archivo en HTML
//esta funcion es el controlador para subir el archivo
function uploadFileControler() {
  // OBTIENE EL ARCHIVO
  var file = document.getElementById("formuploadajax");
  // OBTIENE SOLO EL NOMBRE DEL ARCHIVO
  var fileName = file.files[0].name;

  $('#target').hide();
  $('#mensaje').html(
    '<center><strong>¡Atención!</strong>' +
    'El archivo se está subiendo. ' +
    'Esto puede demorar unos segundos...</center>'
  );

  //guarda la respuesta de si existe o no el archivo
  var existFile = checkFile(fileName);
  responseFile(existFile);
};

//hace una petición al servidor para verificar 
//si existe o no ya el archivo
function checkFile(name){
    var exist = false; //guarda un booleano si existo o no

    //petición para verificar existencia
    $.ajax({
      url: "php/verificarArchivo.php",
      type: "post",
      async: false, //esto hace que el script espere la respuesta del servidor antes de continuar
      data: fileName, //envia unicamente el nombre, lo verifica en php y retorna la respuesta
      success: function(response) {
        //si existe
        if (response === 1) {
          exist = true;
        }
      }
    });

    return exist;
};

//decide si pedir verificación para reemplazar archivo o subirlo de una vez
function responseFile(exist){
  //define que hacer si existe o no existe
  //si existe el archivo
  if (exist) {
    alertify.confirm(
      'El archivo existe, ¿Desea reemplazar?',
      uploadFile(file),
      alertify.error('Se cancelo')
    );
  }else{
    uploadFile(file);
  }
}

//petición para cargar el archivo
function uploadFile(file){
  //formatData para el archivo antes de enviarlo
  var data = new FormData(file);

  //petición
  $.ajax({
    url: "php/uploadimage.php", //php para subir archivo
    type: "post",
    async:false,
    dataType: "html",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
    success: function(r) {
      if (r == 1) {
        alertify.success("Actualizado con exito :)");
      } else {
        alertify.error("Fallo el servidor :(");
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Espero sea Claro, suerte!

Comment: Muchisimas gracias maikol por tu tiempo, la verdad que tengo que estudiar bien tu código para implementarlo. El copy y paste no me funciona jaj. Asigne al evento onclick a la funcion que me indicaste pero no funciona. Tambien necesito toda las variables q cargan con el formulario que acompaña el archivo. Tengo que estudiar un poco mas ajax y jquery (javascript en genera) para poder entender bien q sucede.

Comment: No tiene que ser igual a lo q hice, adecualo a lo que necesitas. La mejor forma de aprender ser es prueba y error ...